# Index of character position in string -- str_locate() and gregexpr() not working

Tags: regex, r, string

I'm trying to find the string position for a "(" parenthesis character in order to make a new variable, but my usual methods aren't working. Both `str_locate()` and `grepexpr()` return an error about invalid regex syntax: `invalid regular expression '(', reason 'Missing ')''`

This could have been a solution: `which(strsplit(df$var, "")[[1]] == "("`, but it doesn't work for making new variables.

Here are some reproducible examples:

```
txt <- "some text (in parentheses)"
df <- structure(list(number = 1:3, txt = c("text (in parentheses)", 
"some text (in parentheses)", "some more text (in parentheses)"
)), .Names = c("number", "txt"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
df

## find position of 'm' -- these all work
stringr::str_locate(txt, "m")[[1]]
gregexpr("m", txt)[[1]][1]

## find position of '(' -- now they don't work
stringr::str_locate(txt, "(")[[1]]
gregexpr("(", txt)[[1]][1]

## find position of '(' -- this works for a character string...
which(strsplit(txt, "")[[1]] == "(")

## ...but not for making a new variable
df$newVar <- which(strsplit(df$txt, "")[[1]] == "(")
df #wrong
```

Comment: Try `gregexpr("\\(", txt)[[1]][1]` because you have to escape `(` which is a special character. Does that work for you?

Comment: No, that runs into the same problem as ```which(strsplit(...))```. All of the ```df$newVar``` values are identical.

Comment: `sapply(df$txt, function(x) str_locate(x, "\\(")[[1]])` works fine for me... Or if you only want the locations `df$newVar <- as.numeric(sapply(df$txt, function(x) str_locate(x, "\\(")[[1]]))`

Comment: If you run `gregexpr("\\(", df$txt)`, the resulting list will have all the correct positions of `(` in `df$txt`. you just need to get them into your `df$newvar`.

Comment: @beginneR Yes, that worked after I got rid of ```[[1]][1]```. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, these both will work

```
df$newVar <- str_locate(df$txt, "\\(")[, 1]
```

Or

```
df$newVar <- sapply(gregexpr("\\(", df$txt), '[', 1)
```